# How to assign a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to panda, and I am struggling with something that should be very easy.

I want to define a script that "collects" some data and stores it in a df called repes when some criteria are met.

This is the code:

```
repes=pd.DataFrame()
for a in df:
    if a.field==

def rarea(x):
    proximo=df[(df.lat>float(x.lat)-0.001)&(df.lat<float(x.lat)+0.001)]
    if len(proximo)==1:
        p2 = proximo.coordenadas
        return len(proximo)
    elif len(proximo)==2:
        repes=repes.append(proximo)
        return len(proximo)
resultado=pd.Series([rarea(robser.iloc[cnt]) for cnt in range (0,len(robser))])`
```

I get the following error "local variable 'repes' referenced before assignment".

How can I initialize the repes dataframe in the beginning?. Why isn't it enough to use repes=pd.DataFrame()? Ehay am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Python "assumes" that we want a `local` variable due to the assignment to `repes` inside of `rarea(x)`, so the first `assignment` statement throws this error message. Any variable which is changed or created inside of a function is local, if it hasn't been declared as a global variable. To tell Python, that we want to use the global variable, we have to use the keyword "global"

`repes` is a global variable.  You have to declare it as global to use it.

```
def rarea(x):
    global repes   # add this line
    proximo=df[(df.lat>float(x.lat)-0.001)&(df.lat<float(x.lat)+0.001)]
```

[Read](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php) more about Global and Local Variables

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much.
I had a big misunderstanding and thought that in python everything (variables and functions) were global. It has been very clarifying. Thank you again.